# Is there any server setting that could disable the ViewState?

Tags: c#, asp.net, iis, viewstate

I'm getting an error because of one page the **ViewState is always lost** after a postback.

This happens only on **one particular machine**. If I take the whole code and move it to **another server** with the same configuration, the code works just fine.

Is there any setting in the IIS that could prevent the ViewState from being in use?

**Note:** It happens only on one page, all other pages that are using the ViewState und Postbacks are working fine.

Comment: if it happens only on one page that means there is no server configuration issue , something to do with that page

Answer (score 0):

ViewState for this page is true, right?

May be you remove form tag ?

Comment: Everything was fine with the ViewState, but I figured out the Problem (see my answer). Thanks anyway!

Answer (score 0):

Allright, a co-worker got the answer:

One machine was a production environment, while the other was just a testing machine. For identification I had a text in the master page, either "Debug" or "Test", but on the production server, I removed the control.

I did it in the *OnLoad Event*, which seems to be terribly wrong, because it crashes the ViewState somehow.